# How to show steps in the QWizard?

Tags: qt

Is there a default way to show wizards steps on the left panel of the wizard?
Or I must to implement custom widget and use setSideWidget() for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately QWizard does not provide a default way to show steps or any other kind of progress information.
Using setSideWidget() seems to be the simplest way to implement this behaviour.
Implementing a custom widget to display the steps and highlight the current one shouldn't be much work...